# How can Hooked-Web3-Provider and Lightwallet work together?

Tags: web3js, light-clients

Does anyone know some good working examples of the Eth-Lightwallet and the Hooked-Web3-Provider working together?

I was trying to get https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet/blob/master/example/example_web.html to work but it aborts with

```
Uncaught Reference Error: web3 is not defined
```

Update: looking for a Meteor implementation.

Comment: Hi Alan, did you fork the lightwallet project? have you solved the problem? Thanks for sharing the solution ;-)

Comment: I didn't need to fork it.  So far, I've succeeded implementing it the way it is but stayed in Meteor 1.2.1 - I plan to upgrade to Meteor 1.3 as it matures. There are good Meteor packages to help. Happy to discuss in more detail.

Comment: FYI: This is old enough now that another library has come on the scene and does it better. Check out the web3-provider-engine which includes a lightwallet and transaction signing subprovider. https://github.com/MetaMask/provider-engine

Answer (score 6):

That, by default, requires you to run your own web3 instance, you can use this one for starting:

[webwallet.html](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet/blob/master/example/webwallet.html)

The complete instructions are:

- Download the git repo (`git clone https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet`), enter the `eth-lightwallet` directory
- Install the npm modules (`npm install`)
- Enter the `examples` directory, open the `webwallet.html` file
- Click the *Create new wallet* button and enter a password

If for some reason the node [entered here](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet/blob/master/example/webwallet.html#L15) is down, replace it with your own node or with another public/testnet node.

Comment: Thanks. Would you also know how to install it into a Meteor app?

Comment: Who manages http://104.236.65.136:8545 ?  And I assume it's the main net?

Comment: I do see it's at Digital Ocean : http://whois.urih.com/record/104.236.65.136/

Comment: I don't know, probably one of the authors of the repo? If that works for you then it means that the code works, now you can switch the ip to a well-known mainnet ip or boot a geth node and connect to it.

Comment: For the sendEth() function example in webwallet.html above, how does the password get passed?  I tested an implementation and web dialog box requests password - how to avoid the dialog and pass a password to it? Thx!

Comment: @AlanWunsche open the webwallet.html file source, find all (4) the entries of "password =", set it to " password = '' " (empty string) by removing all the calls to prompt() and you should be ok, bare in mind that if somebody obtains the seed he can access the funds directly so you should warn the user to keep the seed safe

Comment: Hmmm..I actually noticed that a prompt also sits inside the lightwallet.js code at point of signing a transaction.

Comment: if you really need to, fork it :D